# Set value to nested array subelement

Tags: php, arrays

OK, so here's what I'm trying to do :

- Let's say we've got an array of arrays (of arrays) - *we don't know how many nested arrays there are*.
- And we're given the path (= the indexes) to the element to be set.
- And the value

How's is that doable?

**Example**

Let's say : `putValueAtPosition($arr, "someValue",array(3,5,8));` will set `$arr[3][5][8] = "someValue"` and return the resulting array (the full set).

Any ideas/input is welcome?

---

**P.S.** I'm working on a totally different problem (but with the same core concept) and not even in PHP (doesn't matter though - PHP's clear enough to get the point through! ;-) ), and I've tried all sorts of over-complicated things with recursive functions and passing by reference (or not), my head is about to explode...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested numbering to array keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259773/nested-numbering-to-array-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function putValueAtPosition(&$arr, $val , $path){
    $marker=&$arr;
    foreach($path as $p){
        $marker=&$marker[$p];
    }
    $marker=$val;
}


$test=array(
    1=>array(
        1=>array(
            1=>'cat',
            2=>'hello'
        ),
        2=>'hello'
    ),
    2=>'hello'

);

print_r($test);
putValueAtPosition($test, 'changed', array(1,1,1));
print_r($test);
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! :-)